# Cómo debo usar sed en este caso para eliminar de acuerdo a un patrón, cierto número de veces?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

Tengo en un archivo marcadores moleculares de varios miles de individuos, donde cada individuo tiene 54241 marcadores. Mi problema es que en algunos casos, el individuo está repetido y tengo el doble de marcadores.

Ejemplo:

```
ID         SNP
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4 #Así consecutivamente hasta llegar al a tener 54241, que corresponde al número total de marcadores
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4
ES14005      54241 #ídem
ML15005      1
ML15005      2
ML15005      3
ML15005      4
ML15005      54241 #ídem
```

Y lo que quiero obtener es

```
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4
ES14005      54241
ML15005      1
ML15005      2
ML15005      3
ML15005      4
ML15005      54241
```

¿Cómo hago un comando que elimine las 54241 primeras veces que aparece el ID ES14005?

Usando esto elimina todos los registros:

```
sed -i '/ES14005/d' fichero.txt
```

y usando esto me da error:

```
sed '/ES14005/54241/d'
```

Comment: Necesitaríamos un [mcve], es decir, un ejemplo entero de cómo es un fichero y cómo debe ser tras la modificación que pides.

Comment: El ejemplo entero es imposible de poner porque tengo 780 individuos, cada uno con 54241 marcadores = 42.307.980 líneas.

Comment: bueno pues sustituye 54241 por 3. Algo que sea claro (no conocemos sobre biotecnología) y fácil de reproducir y así tú finalmente sustituirás el 3 por 54241 en el comando que obtengas

Comment: dejé una respuesta, ¿la viste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente quieres eliminar líneas repetidas. Para conseguirlo simplemente debes llevar un registro de las líneas que han aparecido y no imprimirlas de nuevo.

Con awk es apenas una expresión:

```
awk '!visto[$0]++' fichero
```

Es decir, `visto[]` es un vector cuyo índice es el contenido de la línea y cuyo valor es las veces que ha aparecido. Así, `visto[linea]` tendrá el número de veces que el contenido `linea` ha aparecido.

Entonces al decir `!visto[$0]++` lo que hacemos es aumentar el contador y aprovechar su valor de salida: si no ha salido aún, `visto[$0]` devuelve 0 y al negarlo con `!` nos da un valor booleano cierto, con lo que se ejecuta la instrucción de Awk por defecto: imprimir la línea actual. En caso contrario, no imprime nada.

De forma más larga diríamos:

```
awk '{if !($0 in visto) {print}; visto[$0]++}' fichero
```

Con tus datos nos da este resultado:

```
$ cat fichero
ID         SNP
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4
ML15005      1
ML15005      2
ML15005      3
ML15005      4
ML15005      54241
$ awk '!visto[$0]++' fichero 
ID         SNP
ES14005      1
ES14005      2
ES14005      3
ES14005      4
ML15005      1
ML15005      2
ML15005      3
ML15005      4
ML15005      54241
```